# How to understand why logical replication timeout

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I have set up N-1 Postgresql (v12) logical replications: N publisher dbs to 1 subscriber db. And there are replication timeout logs in both pub and sub dbs sometimes:

Subscriber:

```
2023-04-13 15:41:37.908 CST [11272] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
                This probably means the server terminated abnormally
                before or while processing the request.
```

Publisher:

```
2023-04-14 10:19:20.543 CST [48123] LOG:  terminating walsender process due to replication timeout
2023-04-14 10:19:20.543 CST [48123] CONTEXT:  slot "sub_XXXX", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN A/16A7D3C8
```

How could I investigate the root cause of these timeouts?

1. High load on db or node?
2. Network connection?
3. Other?

Comment: Does increasing `wal_sender_timeout` fix the problem?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No. I have increased `wal_sender_timeout=600s` in one publisher but looks no effect.

Comment: After some tests, it turns out to be a problem in timeout/keep alive: there is no timeout error when no data transfer; the error occurs when transfering large amount of wal. 600s is not working so I have to put 0... How to keep alive in data transfer? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: version 12.what ?

Comment: Keepalive should work like with normal connections, see [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tcp-keepalive-for-a-better-postgresql-experience/) for details.

Comment: @jjanes Subscriber: PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit. Publisher: PostgreSQL 12.5 (Debian 12.5-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: Those are very old and should be updated.  I know of at least one big in this area fixed since those releases.  I'm not sure it is what you are seeing, but you need to upgrade anyway say might as well do it first and see if that fixes things.